# Использование COM .dll, Как передать в параметр в виде указателя?

Tags: c++, qt, dll

```
Adaptor->dynamicCall("GetWPlace(long, long*, long*, BSTR*)", i, &DevplaceId,&DevplaceNum,&WPComments);
```

При таком вызове выходит ошибка **QVariant::QVariant(void*)' is private** , при вызове других функций без указателей все происходит нормально.
Код пишу в среде Qt 4.8.4, знаю что подобное работало в Builder 2006.

```
long DevplaceId = 0 ;
long DevplaceNum = 0;
QString WPComments;
long *pDevplaceId = &DevplaceId;
long *pDevplaceNum = &DevplaceNum;
QVariant vdpID = qVariantFromValue((void*)pDevplaceId);
QVariant vdpNum = qVariantFromValue((void*)pDevplaceNum);

int  i = 0;
Adaptor->dynamicCall("FetchWPlaces(long)",7000);
while (DevplaceId != -1)
{

   Adaptor->dynamicCall("GetWPlace(long, long*, long*, BSTR*)",i, vdpID, vdpNum, WPComments);

   long* ptr1 = (long*)vdpID.value<void *>();
   long* ptr2 = (long*)vdpNum.value<void *>();

   DevplaceId = *ptr1;
   DevplaceNum = *ptr2;


   if (DevplaceId != -1)
   {
       qDebug()<< *ptr1 << *ptr2;
       i++;
   }
}
```

В документации нашел такую вещь `void GetWPlace (int Index, int& Id, int& Num, QString& Comments)`

из этого мне следует понять что в функцию стоит передавать ссылки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно документации `QAxBase::dynamicCall()` - в качестве параметров передаются объекты типа `const QVariant&`. Компилятор не знает как привести `long*` к `QVariant` (класс `QVariant` не предоставляет методов для таких преобразований). Возможные пути решения:

1. Попробовать QAxBase::generateDocumentation(). Возможно есть аналогичная функция, которая не использует указатели;
2. Передача `long*` как `QVariant`.
3. Использовать `queryInterface()` и обращаться к функции напрямую.

Если в случае 1 всё довольно очевидно, то в случае 2 придётся использовать операции как в этом коде:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    long dig = 12345;
    long* digPtr = &dig; // Указатель
    qDebug() << digPtr; // Смотрим значение в дебаге
    // "Преобразование" long* в QVariant
    QVariant var = qVariantFromValue((void*) digPtr);
    // "Преобразование" QVariant в long*
    long* ptr = (long*)var.value<void *>();
    qDebug() << ptr; // Смотрим значение(адрес) в дебаге
    ptr++; // 
    qDebug() << ptr; // Смотрим значение(адрес+1) в дебаге

    return a.exec();
}
```

Взято отсюда: http://blog.bigpixel.ro/2010/04/storing-pointer-in-qvariant/.
Решение 3 описано в документации к `QAxBase`: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qaxbase.html

Comment: Ошибка с подачей аргумента исчезла, использовал второй способ, но значения переданные по указателю не меняются, это уже моя ошибка?

Comment: Собственно они и не должны меняться - это адресс переменной. Для получения самого значения нужно пройти по указателю. Я добавил в коде строку, которая это делает.

Comment: Я добавил что я написал в итоге, и все равно ничего не меняется, выходят 0 и 0 постоянно

Comment: Зависит от того, что подразумевается под _"значения переданные по указателю не меняются"_. Всё, что будет происходить с переменной, зависит от реализации GetWPlace(...). dynamicCall() фактически просто отдаёт свои параметры (в данном случае long, long*...) функции GetWPlace(...), так что если что-то не просходит - надо смотреть GetWPlace(...).

Comment: Какова роль i (первый параметр) в функции GetWPlace(...)? Можете представить её реализацию и описание, что она должна делать?

Comment: она должна возвращать из базы ID и NUM, i это видимо просто номер записи, я не могу узнать саму реализацию GetWPlace(...)

Comment: Если верить документации, все параметры передадутся в GetWPlace(...) в виде строк. Правильная работа будет зависеть от контрола - сможет ли он правильно интерпретировать. Также, можно попробовать Adaptor->generateDocumentation() - возможно есть аналогичная функция, не использующая указатели. И, в конце концов, можно использовать queryInterface() и вызывать функции напрямую.